# how to find for which view display_override hook is using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I am using display_override hook, I want to invoke this hook only for few views, not all view pages, how to implement check for this ? using codeigniter

Comment: What kind of hook you are using? Some code would help.

Comment: I am using display_override hook

Comment: Post code you are using so far with error you're getting. Check [how to ask](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: _display() deals with the final output that's to be sent to browser; it has nothing to do with loading views as it only deal with the combined html output.